# esp8266 issue when trying to connect to the internet

Tags: http, arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I use this code and try to connect my esp8266 so it will upload temperature to thingspeak.com

```c++
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// LED 
int ledPin = 13;
// LM35 analog input
int lm35Pin = A0;

// replace with your channel's thingspeak API key
String apiKey = "xxxxxx";
// connect 10 to TX of Serial USB
// connect 11 to RX of serial USB
SoftwareSerial ser(10, 11); // RX, TX


void setup() {                

  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);    


  Serial.begin(115200); 

  ser.begin(115200);


  ser.println("AT+RST");
}



void loop() {


  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);   
  delay(200);               
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);


  int val = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      val += analogRead(lm35Pin);   
      delay(500);
  }


  float temp = val*50.0f/1023.0f;


  char buf[16];
  String strTemp = dtostrf(temp, 4, 1, buf);

  Serial.println(strTemp);


  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += "184.106.153.149"; // api.thingspeak.com
  cmd += "\",80";
  ser.println(cmd);

  if(ser.find("Error")){
    Serial.println("AT+CIPSTART error");
    return;
  }


  String getStr = "GET /update?api_key=";
  getStr += apiKey;
  getStr +="&field1=";
  getStr += String(strTemp);
  getStr += "\r\n\r\n";


  cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  cmd += String(getStr.length());
  ser.println(cmd);

  if(ser.find(">")){
    ser.print(getStr);
  }
  else{
    ser.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");

    Serial.println("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  }


  delay(16000);  
}
```

When running the code i get this in the serial monitor:

```
21
AT+CIPCLOSE
21
AT+CIPCLOSE
21
AT+CIPCLOSE
```

21 will be the temperature

Answer (score 0):

On the firmware version that I use the return for a failure on AT+CIPSTART is "ERROR" and not "Error" so that might be the reason why you never see that the connection has failed. Try the above via a serial Terminal connected to the ESP8266 and check what the returns are.

Also, you need to learn to stay away from Strings in AVR programming. Rather use char arrays.